# Blink only specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have to make blinking text but only where the text = "something". I already have working mechanism but dont know where can i put this condition, can you help?:

```
css:
 .blink {
        color: #FFF !important;
        background: #FC79CE;

    }

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        blink(".msgblink", 4, 500);
    });

    function blink(elem, times, speed) {
        if (times > 0 || times < 0) {
            if ($(elem).hasClass("blink"))
                $(elem).removeClass("blink");
            else
                $(elem).addClass("blink");
        }

        clearTimeout(function () { blink(elem, times, speed); });

        if (times > 0 || times < 0) {
            setTimeout(function () { blink(elem, times, speed); }, speed);
            times -= .5;
        }
    }

</script>
```

where inside this script i could specify blink only where text = "something"?

**UPDATE:**

```
<th class="grid-header msgblink" title="MessageType"><div class="grid-filter" data-filterdata="[]" data-name="MessageType" data-type="System.String" data-widgetdata="null"><span class="grid-filter-btn" title="Filter this column"></span></div><div class="grid-header-title"><a href="?grid-column=MessageType&amp;grid-dir=0">MessageType</a></div></th>

<td class="grid-cell msgblink" data-name="MessageType"> INFO something</td>
```

Comment: In your blink function, you can use $(elem).val() to get the value and toggle the blink class accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small modification to your original code, which works and you can easilly change text you are  searching for:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //blink(".msgblink", 4, 500);
    $(".msgblink").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf('something') !== -1) {
            blink(this, 4, 500);
        }
    });
});

function blink(elem, times, speed) {
    if (times > 0 || times < 0) {
        if ($(elem).hasClass("blink")) $(elem).removeClass("blink");
        else $(elem).addClass("blink");
    }

    clearTimeout(function () {
        blink(elem, times, speed);
    });

    if (times > 0 || times < 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            blink(elem, times, speed);
        }, speed);
        times -= .5;
    }
}
```

```css
.blink {
    color: #FFF !important;
    background: #FC79CE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="msgblink">something</div>
<div class="msgblink">nothing</div>
<div class="msgblink">something</div>
<div class="msgblink">another</div>
<table>
<th class="grid-header msgblink" title="MessageType"><div class="grid-filter" data-filterdata="[]" data-name="MessageType" data-type="System.String" data-widgetdata="null"><span class="grid-filter-btn" title="Filter this column"></span></div><div class="grid-header-title"><a href="?grid-column=MessageType&amp;grid-dir=0">MessageType</a></div></th>
<tr>
<td class="grid-cell msgblink" data-name="MessageType"> INFO something</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: dont know why but for after implemented it its not working

Comment: Well, if you can create jsfiddle, or share url of the page where it is not working, it will be easier to help. Do you see some error in console?

Comment: got some error in console (note that the page is loaded correctly just no blinking): "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" http ://localhost:60243/__browserLink/requestData/5d4ab75d71984f6599db9bd69cbbac76

Comment: Is jquery loaded? Is `$(document).ready(function () {` executed?

Comment: i did exactly how you posted.

Comment: Change `$(document).ready(function () {` to `$(document).ready(function () {alert('loaded');` and see if alert pops up. If it doesn't then event is not fired.

Comment: Are you dynamically generating/adding content from javascript or ajax, or full page html content is initially loaded? If you are dynamically adding, you need to run `$(".msgblink").each(function () {` after that. Can you post somewhere html of your page, or url, to check. Like this it is difficult to guess what is the problem..

Comment: this is done within asp net page. What should i change to get it work

Comment: what can be wrong? So far only @Pranay Rana example was working but his text === is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you more without seeing actual html of your page.

Comment: check main post on UPDATE section i paste a piece of html generated on page with msgblink class. The code from oryginal post is working but all everything in this column blinking including column header

Comment: Ah, so you want to blink if text `contains` "sometext", not only to be `exactly` "sometext". Check my updated answer, part: `if ($(this).text().indexOf('something') !== -1) {`

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of [.Contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector of jquery for this i.e. to check your text in html of ele you are going to blink.

Example :

```
$( "div:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
```

Your blink function may be like as below

```
function blink(elem, times, speed) { 
  var id=   $(elem).prop("id");
  if($("#" +id + ":contains('John')" )
  {
    //your code to adding class
  }
}
```

or if you are checking text is eq to somehting than

```
function blink(elem, times, speed) { 
  alert($(elem).val())
  if($(elem).val()==="something" )///for input element 
  //if($(elem).text()==="something" )//for other html element like div,span etc.
  {
    //your code to adding class
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is running.

Comment: look at my main post in UPDATE section i modyfy as you adviced but its not working.

Comment: @StackUser - try to alert value of val i.e. alert($("#" +id).val()) and check it is giving you a value or not

Comment: can you put this change within your answer, i am not so familiar with jquery if you could do so.

Comment: @StackUser - update code try that ...one moer thing if you element is not input element use html here

Comment: unfortunetly also not working :  if($(elem).text()==="something" )

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
function blink(elem, times, speed) {
   if (elem.text() != "something") { 
     return;
   }
   // rest of code
```